# Angular 6 throttleTime doesnt exist in Rx Js

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular6

I am using `angular/cli": "~6.1.5`  and `rxjs": "^6.0.0`
As i new to Angular 6 i started learning from official document

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

code is below

```
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
var result = clicks.throttleTime(1000);
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Same above code i tried in angular 6

```
fromEvent(mybuttonId, 'click')
      .subscribe((event) => console.log('clicked'));
```

But if i add .throttleTime(1000) to from event then it will throw error

> Property 'throttleTime' does not exist on type 'Observable

'`.

if i try to add Observable.fromEvent then that method doesn't exist

I have imported Rx js as

```
import {Observable, fromEvent, from, of} from 'rxjs';
import {throttleTime} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Can any one help me where i can find exact document for latest version.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be piped on to an Observable like this:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

subscription = fromEvent(document, 'click')
               .pipe(throttleTime(1000))
               .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

You can find it in the Official Docs here:

[fromEvent](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html) | [throttleTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttletime.html)

Also make sure to `unsubscribe` from the `subscription` to avoid any memory leaks. Generally, this is done in `ngOnDestroy`

Comment: @Siddarth as i said Property 'fromEvent' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Comment: i cant access fromEvent from observable.only it works if access fromevent directly

Comment: @Siddharth.i  have tired this before asking question my problem is ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(35,29): error TS2339: Property 'fromEvent' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Siddharth Ajmera for the clue for using pipe.
In latest Version of rx js we can do as below

```
 fromEvent(this.hoverSection, 'click')
      .pipe(throttleTime(1000))
      .subscribe((event) => console.log('clicked'));
```